# Outlook mail doesn't show image thumbnail when sent using symfony mailer

Tags: symfony, outlook, email-attachments, hotmail, symfony-mailer

I am using Symfony mailer in my Laravel app. The issue is that when I send image as attachment outlook web shows image thumbnail as white document, when I send the same image manually the thumnail is generetated for the image. Also other mail clients like gmail show image regullary. I understand that the issue is on the outlook side, but I was wondering if there is anything I can do on my side.

this the part of the code where I add attachment
`addPart(new DataPart(new File($srcImage), pathinfo($srcImage, PATHINFO_FILENAME)))`

Comment: You really need to compare the MIME source of the message in the two cases.

Comment: Dmitry is correct, the best what you could start from is to compare emails to find any difference.